DBeaver: "Presentation" Button Not Working - No Underlying Browser Available
I'm experiencing an issue with DBeaver where the "Presentation" button is not working. When I try to use it, I receive the following error:
# **No more handles because there is no underlying browser available. Please ensure that WebKit with its GTK 3.x/4.x bindings are installed.
# **

enter image description here
I have confirmed that webkit2gtk, gtk3, and gtk4 are installed on my Arch Linux system. Here are the relevant command outputs:
pacman -Qs webkit2gtk
local/webkit2gtk 2.46.0-2
Web content engine for GTK
sudo pacman -S webkit2gtk gtk3 gtk4 --needed
warning: webkit2gtk-2.46.0-2 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gtk3-1:3.24.43-3 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gtk4-1:4.16.2-1 is up to date -- skipping
there is nothing to do
**
I have already tried:

Reinstalling DBeaver.
Moving the DBeaver configuration folder to backup.
Running DBeaver with GDK_BACKEND=x11 LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 dbeaver.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists.

Try webkit2gtk-4.1 and webkitgtk-6.0?
